# Error handling when running a VBA macro in opened worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write some code that will run arbitrary macros from different worksheets than the one I'm in, with elegant error handling.

I am trying to do this by utilising On Error Resume Next, however this seems to only have scope within the worksheet I am running from. I have tried activating the target worksheet first, but this didn't work.

My current code looks something like the following:

```vb
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
wbTarget.Activate
On Error Resume Next
Application.Run (wbTarget.Name & "!ErrorProducingMacro")
On Error Goto 0
wbThis.Activate
```

I am testing this on a macro that produces an error, which I would expect my code to ignore, however it is displaying the error as though On Error Resume Next were not called. Is there a way to set the error handling of a target workbook that anyone is aware of?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749778/on-error-scope-vba). Btw - `On Error Resume Next` would normally not be classified as "elegant error handling," as it doesn't handle the error at all :)

Comment: Oh yeah totally - the finished code will do some stuff with Err.Description.

That question seems to imply that my code should work as expected, except that it doesn't? Is this because the target workbook's native error handling is overwriting it?

Comment: Which line shows up when error occurs ?

Comment: The line within ErrorProducingMacro - `Err.Raise 1`

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to surpass error handling in other workbook and also not prudent. It is better to use `On Error Resume Next` in the module. However you you are hell bent to do that from remote i.e. `ThisWorkbook`  and don't  intent to save the opened workbook.may use the lines below. to insert a line in the module `Ln = Wb.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.ProcStartLine("boom", 0)` 
`Wb.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.InsertLines Ln + 1, "On Error Resume Next"`
`Run Wb.Name & "!boom"` or something like this

Comment: replace `Wb` `Module1`  and `Boom` to your choice.

Comment: Nice one - should be `Ln + 2` but otherwise seems to work, thanks!

Comment: @TrickedCoffee Welcome, You made my day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per Ahmed AU - something like

```vb
Ln = Wb.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.ProcStartLine("ErrorProducingMacro", 0) 
Wb.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.InsertLines Ln + 2, "On Error Resume Next" 
Run Wb.Name & "!ErrorProducingMacro"
```